# Having difficulty white listing a chrome app for Chromecast

Tags: google-cast

I have successfully whitelisted my Chromecast device, however while trying to whitelist a local Chrome App as a sender I have run into difficulty with the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/cast/whitelisting#whitelist-chrome) saying

1. Be sure you are running Chrome version 28 or later.
2. If you haven't restarted Chrome in a while you may be running an older version; restarting will update Chrome automatically.
3. In the Chrome omnibox, enter chrome://extensions, and check the Developer mode checkbox to enable developer mode.
4. Install the Chrome extension for Google Cast.

**5. On the Cast icon in Chrome's upper right corner, click four (4) times.**

**6. In the Cast extension, scroll to the Developer options.**

**7. In the Cast SDK additional domains field, click Add and enter the domain of your application, for example, "www.mydomain.com."**

Code your application's HTML tag as follows:

---

When I click on the chromecast icon 4 times I get no developer menu, making it impossible for me to whitelist my chrome app. Am I doing something wrong or going about it the wrong way?

I am using Chrome 28.0.1500.71 on Mac OS X 10.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open up Chromecast options from the extension, and then click the cast icon in the **top left corner** repeatedly (4+ times), and developer options should show up at the bottom.

Documentation is incorrect, found this out through trial and error.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is currently incorrect. To view the developer SDK menu, click the chrome cast extension icon in chrome, click options, then click the google cast icon in the upper left corner a bunch of time. It isn't 4 times, but if you click 4 times, wait and click twice more, I've been able to get it to come up.

This will give the option to input a domain which will cause the google cast extension to inject the API into pages on that domain.

Make sure not to include http or the path. In my testing it seems to wildcard match so example.com will match cast.example.com and castqa.example.com.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the chromecast icon and goto options.  Then click the icon at the top of the page 4 times.

I personally had to click options then right click on the option page and inspect element.  In the Div with the class options-selections class on it change the 5th section element to display:block;

Or.. Goto the console and put this in:

```
first = document.getElementsByClassName('options-sections')[0]
first.getElementsByTagName('section')[4].style.display = 'block';
```

If you look around there are other sections hidden in here.  Might be other goodies of use.

Comment: Clever, did not think to try something like this.

Comment: If I would've dug a little further I probably would've found that their documentation was incorrect as @mr mr said.